# Validating webhook with sha256 hmac using PHP and Python

Tags: python, php, json, sha256, hmac

I am working with webhooks from Bold Commerce, which are validated using a hash of the timestamp and the body of the webhook, with a secret key as the signing key. The headers from the webhook looks like this :

```
X-Bold-Signature: 06cc9aab9fd856bdc326f21d54a23e62441adb5966182e784db47ab4f2568231
timestamp: 1556410547
Content-Type: application/json
charset: utf-8
```

According to their documentation, the hash is built like so  (in PHP):

```
$now = time(); // current unix timestamp
$json = json_encode($payload, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $now.'.'.$json, $signingKey);
```

I am trying to recreate the same hash using python, and I am always getting the wrong value for the hash. I've tried several combinations, with and without base64 encoding. In python3, a bytes object is expected for the hmac, so I need to encode everything before I can compare it. At this point my code looks like so :

```
json_loaded = json.loads(request.body)
json_dumped = json.dumps(json_loaded)

# if I dont load and then dump the json, the message has escaped \n characters in it 

message = timestamp + '.' + json_dumped
# =>  1556410547.{"event_type" : "order.created", "date": "2020-06-08".....}

hash = hmac.new(secret.encode(), message.encode(), hashlib.sha256)
hex_digest = hash.hexdigest()
# => 3e4520c869552a282ed29b6523eecbd591fc19d1a3f9e4933e03ae8ce3f77bd4

# hmac_to_verify = 06cc9aab9fd856bdc326f21d54a23e62441adb5966182e784db47ab4f2568231

return hmac.compare_digest(hex_digest, hmac_to_verify)
```

Im not sure what I am doing wrong. For the other webhooks I am validating, I used base64 encoding, but it seems like here, that hasnt been used on the PHP side. I am not so familiar with PHP so maybe there is something I've missed in how they built the orginal hash. There could be complications coming from the fact that I have to convert back and forth between byte arrays and strings, maybe I am using the wrong encoding for that ? Please someone help, I feel like I've tried every combination and am at a loss.

EDIT : Tried this solution by leaving the body without encoding it in json and it still fails :

```
print(type(timestamp)
# => <class 'str'>
print(type(body))
# => <class 'bytes'>

# cant concatenate bytes to string... 
message = timestamp.encode('utf-8') + b'.' + body

# => b'1556410547.{\n    "event_type": "order.created",\n    "event_time": "2020-06-08 11:16:04",\n ...
hash = hmac.new(secret.encode(), message, hashlib.sha256)
hex_digest = hash.hexdigest()
# ...etc
```

EDIT EDIT :

Actually it is working in production ! Thanks to the solution described above (concatenating everything as bytes). My Postman request with the faked webhook was still failing, but that's probably because of how I copied and pasted the webhook data from my heroku logs :) .

Comment: Depending on the specific parameters used, decoding and re-encoding as JSON, can lead to results that are different from the original input data. It is usually better to take the request body content as-is (in text form), and calculate the hash directly based on that value.

Comment: Thank you that was the solution ! I had to leave the body alone and convert the timestamp to bytes instead.